# How do I charge my professor hourly for Web Scraping?

Tags: research-process, salary, research-assistantship

I am a graduate research assistant, who is paid hourly, I run a script that scrapes data for my professor's research. It is automated, meaning that I don't have to even click a button. But it runs for 1.5 hours everyday on my laptop. I get paid hourly. Do I clock in for the 1.5 hours on a daily basis at the time when my scrape starts? or do I not clock in at all since I don't physically do anything for the 1.5 hours?

Comment: What happens once the script has finished  - collation, compressing etc sending etc is time that should be paid...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As always, talk to your professor and ask him/her!

If I paid a student to write a script, I would just run it on my own machine or a department machine. You aren't working so it seems disingenuous to accept payment for it, unless the professor knows he/she is essentially just renting your computer to run the script.

Comment: That was the joke about the computer specialist at the pearly gates, he was complaining he should die as he was only 38 - the reply was “according to the time you have charged your clients you are 84”...

Answer (score 1):

> [my professor] runs [a script] for 1.5 hours everyday on my laptop...[Should I get paid whilst the script runs?]

You are presumably doing other work whilst the script is running? So, yes, you should get paid. On the other hand, if the script is consuming your laptop resources in a manner that precludes other work, then you should reschedule the script to run when it doesn't preclude other work (e.g., over night or early morning).